# How to make modal Window in UWP and return value when it is closed

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I need to implement some functionality in a second `Window` in **UWP**.

So I want to do following

> 1. Start new `Window` in a Modal state so parent `Window` cannot be acceced.
> 2. On closed event  return **value** to the parent `Window`.

I use following code to create a new Window please help me to archive these points

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var switchToView = true;

            var newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
            int newViewId = 0;
            await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var frame = new Frame();
                frame.Navigate(typeof(MyCam), null);
                Window.Current.Content = frame;

                newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            });
            var viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
            if (switchToView && viewShown)
            {
                // Switch to new view
                await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(newViewId);
            }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nice solution here 
https://github.com/bkaankose/UWPModalDialogHelper

It is about to use `Prism.Core` Nuget package to simulate  fullscreen popup with custom UserControl.